# datasource is not returning value for the 2nd row even after binding for birt report

Tags: dataset, report, datasource, birt, dynamic-text

I have created a report using scripted datasource.I had to do some mathematical operations for calculating something so I used a dynamic text.
Now the problem is that the value coming in dynamic text is correct for the first row.But for the second row it uses the same values which was used in 1st row,And not the values which are present in 2nd row of datasource.

Can anyone tell me how to map the values considering I have already binded the data.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

Maybe you are binding at the wrong level? Remember that if you bind a DataSet directly to a DynamicText item, it will always show the first row returned.
To display more than one row, you have to bind the DS to a List or Table item.

Be aware that the data engine caches results - for scripted DataSets as well as for JDBC DataSets. So, if your DS results are depending on some context, you have to pass this context as a DS parameter to the to the DS.